# SSRS header text not changing from Bold

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I build a SSRS report. In both edit and preview mode it show the headers for the columns in normal non bold. However when I run the same SSRS report from our report server the header text shows up as bold. I tried removing the report multiple times. I tried clearing my internet cache and nothing. Any ideas?

Update: I uploaded same report(With changes) to server but with different name and everything is the same on the report.

Update 2: I show NO cache on for the reports. I tried rebooting the server that has both SSRS and SQL running on it and no change. Thinking it may be within the report but after checked I do not see anything that would cause it.

Update 3 for Jerry: 
`<TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="nop123">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Number of Parts</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <TextDecoration>None</TextDecoration>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style>
                                <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                              </Style>
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                            </Border>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                            <WritingMode>Rotate270</WritingMode>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                        <rd:Selected>true</rd:Selected>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>`

Comment: Are you using a standard font for that header text?

Comment: Arial, 10 pt, style default,weight default and text decoration as default. I did have it "Bold" at one time but changed it back since it was ugly.

Comment: please check if report is not cached on report server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157447%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: No change. See update above

Comment: Name one of the column headers something unusual, like "headercheckit" or something. Export the report to .rdl on the hard drive, and look at the file in Notepad. What does the formatting for that field look like?

Comment: Jerry Ritcey I posted code above.